# WKWebView strange behaviour when opening target="_blank" links on OS X

Tags: macos, webview, webkit, wkwebview

I am developing an **OS X wrapper** around a popular **web application**, using WKWebView. However, when I try to open a link from the app, I get this strange behaviour:

- tap on the link (the link has `target="_blank"`)
- [`webView:createWebViewWithConfiguration:forNavigationAction:windowFeatures:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKUIDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/WKUIDelegate/webView:createWebViewWithConfiguration:forNavigationAction:windowFeatures:) is called
- trying to extract the url from the `navigationAction` parameter in the delegate method above I get an empty URL
- [`webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:completionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKUIDelegate_Ref/index.html) method is called with the following message parameter: `"Grrr! A popup blocker may be preventing the application from opening the page. If you have a popup blocker, try disabling it to open the window."`

Has anyone experienced anything similar? My idea is that they are doing something fancy with their javascript to track clicks and this is blocking the normal link behaviour.